# Can't find Apex Jobs that are blocking deployment

Tags: apex, deployment, metadata-api, asyncapexjob, salesforce-support

I am trying to delete a couple of old unused Apex Classes in our Production. Every time I try to delete all or one of them I get the following error message:
"This apex class is referenced elsewhere in salesforce.com. Remove the usage and try again.: Apex Job - 7070900003iTBOz."
(This Message occurs for every class that I want to delete and some classes get multiple of them)

The Problem is that the stated Apex Jobs in the error message are not findable and/or deleteable in the org.
What I have tried so far:

- Search with SOQL in the `AsyncApexJob` Object for the Jobs (with the 15-Character and 18-Character Version)
- Execute `System.abortJob()` (with the 15-Character and 18-Character Version)
- Execute `System.purgeOldAsyncJobs` (with the Date set to `Date.today()` and also `Date.today().addDays(1)`) and wait a few days for Apex Sharing Recalculation to execute
- Delete the Class(es) with Ant Migration Tool
- Delete the Class(es) with VS-Code and Salesforce Extensions
- Delete the Class(es) with Workbench
- Modify one the Classes, deploy it and retry to delete them (to trigger recompilation)

Articles that I read to resolve the issue:
[Cannot delete, no references but still says referenced elsewhere in salesforce.com](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/3314/cannot-delete-no-references-but-still-says-referenced-elsewhere-in-salesforce-c)

[Why is this Apex Class dependent on a bunch of completed Apex Jobs?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/61056/why-is-this-apex-class-dependent-on-a-bunch-of-completed-apex-jobs)
(The difference in my case to this question is that I can´t even query the jobs)

Does anyone have any more ideas or suggestions how I can delete the classes and get rid of the error message?

Comment: Hey could you check this thread out : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1585/ghost-schedulable-classes-blocking-deployment

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! Unfortunately the article could not help me, but describes a very similar situation :)
(The support is already contacted and stopping all scheduable jobs as well as activating deployments while Apex jobs are active could unfortunately not help either)

Comment: [perhaps useful](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/173219/2602)

Comment: Definitely falls into the same range! Unfortunately, with both API version 58 and API version 31 I get the message "System.StringException: Job does not exist or is already aborted."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contact Salesforce Support. They will be able hard delete those jobs for you.

Comment: Thanks! Already contacted them two days ago but it will probably take some time until I will be forwarded to someone who can do this

Comment: **Update:** I spoke to SF support this morning and they confirmed that there were some "_bad references_" that were only visible from their backend and could only be deleted by them. Now everything works fine again.