# Destructive Deployment Error: This apex class is referenced elsewhere in salesforce.com. Remove the usage and try again. : Apex Job - 7073u0000******

Tags: apex, asyncapexjob

I am trying to delete a batch class from production that was 1) scheduled and 2) called from another batch class which was also scheduled.

The reference to this class was removed from the second batch class and all scheduled jobs terminated.  The changed class was deployed.

However, upon trying to delete the original class upon a second deployment (of the destructive change only), I am still getting this error:

`This apex class is referenced elsewhere in salesforce.com. Remove the usage and try again. : Apex Job - 7073u0000*****`

Frustratingly, that Job Id (the real Id, not the obfuscated one) doesn't exist in the `AsyncApexJob` table.

So, my problem: All references to the class were removed, all jobs were unscheduled, and I'm getting an error saying it is referenced in a job for which the Id doesn't exist on my system.  Is there a way to query a recycle bin or something similar for the jobs table?

Comment: Contact support. Along similar lines: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/407388/cant-find-apex-jobs-that-are-blocking-deployment

Comment: Ah, bummer what a hassle!  Thanks.